# Unknown 16 bit gray image file format with no header

Tags: java, image, grayscale, image-formats

i only got the image data with NO header informations but i know several things like:

- 16 bit grayscale data
- 1200x1200 (although its 1200x900 but its likely to have a "bar" at the buttom)
- the data are 2880000 bytes in size which fits 1200x1200 x 2bytes ->short
  [here is the raw image data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xz4b8f1apy1bqd8/rohbild.gray?dl=0)
  for visualizing i use this:

```
    public static void saveImage(short[] pix, int width, int height, File outputfile) {
        ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
        int[] nBits = {16};
        ComponentColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(cs, nBits,false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);
        SampleModel sm = cm.createCompatibleSampleModel(width, height);
        DataBufferShort db = new DataBufferShort(pix, width*height);
        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sm, db, null);
        BufferedImage bf = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, false, null);
        if(outputfile!=null)
            try {
                if(!ImageIO.write(bf, "png", outputfile)) System.out.println("No writer found.");
                System.out.println("Saved: "+outputfile.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        else System.out.println("error");
    }
```

The data are read like this (only experimental/bad code, its only for testing):

```
            for(int tt=1; tt<20; tt++) {
                pix = new short[1200*1200];
                i = 0;
                int z = 0;
                int line = 0;
                //loop
                while(i<(1200*1200)) {
                    pix[i++] = buffer.getShort(z);
                    z += tt;
                    if(z>=(len-1)) {
                        line += 2;
                        z = line;
                        if(z>=(len-1)) {
                            System.out.println("break at "+z);
                            break;
                        }
                        System.out.println("test "+line);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("img_"+imgcount+".png "+pix.length);
                saveImage(pix, 1200, 1200, new File("img_"+imgcount+"_"+tt+".png"));
            }
```

Where i can see something for tt=4,8,16 (images get multiplied) but i cant realy get the whole picture.[image tt=8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voSqe.jpg)   [image tt=16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nd8m.jpg)
Its like the solution is in front of me but i cant see it xD
Can someone help me with the algorithm/format the image is stored?

**EDIT:** Reading data consecutively with:

```
            short[] pix = new short[1200*1200];
            int i = 0;
            while(i< (1200*1200) && buffer.remaining()>0) {
                pix[i++] = buffer.getShort();
            }
```

results in: [noisy picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9nyF.jpg)

**EDIT 2:**
Ok looks like its base64 encoded which makes sense due its stored in a xml file

Comment: Can you explain why you read your buffer the way you do? Why don't you read the shorts consecutively?

Comment: reading the data as a chain results just in a noisy gray image where u cant see anything, so the data isnt just stored in a single chain.

Comment: i added a picture

Comment: First, I'd do `ShortBuffer sb = buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer(); sb.get(pix,0,sb.remaining();` instead of your lengthy loop. Then if I got the random image, I'd try the same with `ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN`. If it's still random, I'd still need an explanation of why you chose that algorithm, what you think it does, what `len` is etc.

Comment: the algorithm isnt correct yet, because i dont know in which order the data is stored. It looks like that it is not simply stored in a straight line more like every 8 byte (4 shorts). Besides that it seems that i have to order the lines... so kind of realy complicated and im not that into image formats. I just used error and try to determine the correct byte sequence

Comment: Big/little endian i already first tried, didnt worked. but retried it again ;) no improvement, got worse. ```len = buffer.limit()``` sorry forgot to post

Answer (score 0):

I finaly solved it, its base64 encoded and little endian (thanks RealSkeptic for hinting to try little/big endian).